# How to syntax highlight XML in reStructuredTest/Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

What is the suggested way of adding xml in Sphinx/reST so that it gets properly displayed in the generated doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself. We should use the code-block directive with 'xml' as the value

Comment: Which looks like this, directly before the code block `.. code-block:: xml`